# Node.js and Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, serverside-javascript

I am trying to link up a redis database with a Node.js application I am building to be able to store comments about items. I'm using the node_redis library to handle the connection. When I attempt to retrieve the comments out of the database however only "[true]" is returned. For testing purposes I have stuffed everything into one method and I have hardcoded the values in, but I still receive "[true]".

```
exports.getComment = function (id){

var comments = new Array();

rc.hmset("hosts", "mjr", "1", "another", "23", "home", "1234");

comments.push(rc.hgetall("hosts", function (err, obj) {

    var comment = new Array();

    if(err){
        comment.push("Error");
    } else {
        comment.push(obj);
    }

    return comment;
}));

return comments;

}
```

**Updated** the code according to the tutorial and here is the result:

Retrieving the comment:

```
exports.getComment = function (id, callback){

  rc.hgetall(id, callback);

}
```

Adding the comment:

```
exports.addComment = function (id, area, content, author){

//add comment into the database
rc.hmset("comment", 
         "id", id, 
         "area", area, 
         "content", content,
         "author" , author,
         function(error, result) {
            if (error) res.send('Error: ' + error);
         });

//returns nothing

};
```

Code to render:

```
var a = [];
require('../lib/annotations').addComment("comment");
require('../lib/annotations').getComment("comment", function(comment){
    a.push(comment)
});
res.json(a);
```

Comment: Chris Maness: please update your question, not my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lays within the actual Redis-Node library when the call to addComment is made as it is below.

```
require('../lib/annotations').getComment("comment", function(comment){
    a.push(comment)
});
```

This call is missing an argument in the callback function. The first argument is the error report which should return null if everything is ok, the second is the actual data. So it should be structured like the call below.

```
require('../lib/annotations').getComment("comment", function(comment){
    a.push(err, comment)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is **asynchronous**. Which means it asynchronously does the redis stuff, and then gets the result back in the callback function.

I suggest you read this tutorial and fully understand it before getting further: http://howtonode.org/node-redis-fun

Basically, this way won't work:

```
function getComments( id ) {
    var comments = redis.some( action );
    return comments;
}
```

But it has to be this way:

```
function getComments( id, callback ) {
    redis.some( action, callback );
}
```

This way, you use the API like this:

```
getComments( '1', function( results ) {
    // results are available!
} );
```

Comment: In other words, return comments is happening before return comment

Comment: And `return` happens before the datas are even set (I'm pretty sure `hmset` hasn't finished when the `return` is done).

Comment: So how can I ensure that the hmset happens before the hmget

Comment: @ChrisManess Read the tutorial and understand it before getting further. You should understand how *asynchronous* works and easily find out what's wrong in your code.

Comment: @ChrisManess I edited my answer, hope it's not too hard to grasp the concept.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Thanks for taking time and explaining this. I only have one other question about the example. When you show the get comments function are those two separate callbacks or is it just passed into the redis function?

Comment: @ChrisManess It is just passed in the redis function. So the redis function will do some action, and once it is done, it will run the `callback` function with the correct datas in the arguments. Which is why the anonymous function will have the correct results.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine When I try this it only returns a null value. Even with the set happening before it.

Comment: @ChrisManess Did you read the tutorial? What's your new code after it?